# How do I receive Celebi from the Pokemon Bank?

Tags: pokemon-bank

The Pokebank is now available in the European region & Australia.

I've downloaded the application from the Nintendo e-shop, but when I ran it I only received an option for a gift of Pokemiles or Battle Points.

How do I claim the Celebi gift?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that this Celebi event has ended, thus is no longer obtainable as a prize from Pokebank.

Original instructions:

---

You will receive Celebi the SECOND time you run the Pokebank.

The steps I took were:

- Ran the Pokebank for the first time, agreed to the terms & free trial
- Chose a gift option (choice between Battle Points & Pokemiles)
- Transferred some Pokémon to the Bank
- Went and claimed the Battle Points from the Pokemon Start Menu 'Link Gift' option (screenshot below)
- Loaded & Saved the game
- Quit and went back into the Pokebank
- Received Celebi

<strike>I am not sure if you need to transfer Pokemon or simply close and reopen the Pokebank in order to receive Celebi</strike> According to a few different reports you don't need to transfer Pokemon at all, just close and reopen the Pokebank - but those are the steps I took.

Pokemon link option on the main menu:
[image: Pokemon link option on the main menu]