# How do you get Pokémiles or Battle Points from the Pokémon Bank

Tags: pokemon-bank

I've deposited and withdrawn some Pokemon but when I go to Pokemon link it says no data!

How do I get the rewards?

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but getting battle points/pokemiles is also covered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/154704/58396).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by no data?

Answer (score 1):

Did you talk to Brigette explaining whether you wanted 100 pokemiles or 10 battle points? There is also a 3rd option, to not receive either, which you may have pressed. I believe re-entering the pokebank application will bring up a conversation with Brigette where you can choose.