# Do they have the free trials for Pokebank in Australia?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I really want that Celebi.... And I know we've got ages until September, but I want the free trail for the pokebank, paying is annoying. Is it available in Australia? And if it is, can someone tell me how to get it within 30 days (free trial time limit)

Comment: It should have been made available through eShop for Australia when it was made available in Europe. Can you find the downloadable software in eShop? If you can see it, follow the instructions on [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/154704/58396) then.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2014/2/4/5376906/pokemon-bank-live-in-europe-australia-and-new-zealand), there was a free trial for Pokebank when it launched in "Europe, Australia and New Zealand". However, the trial ended on March 14th.

This means that if you still want the promotional Celebi, you'll need to pay the $4.99 subscription fee and follow the steps outlined in [this answer,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154703/how-do-i-receive-celebi-from-the-pokemon-bank/154704#154704) as Jerry pointed out in the comments of your question.